# How to properly assign values to a List of selectlistitem type model in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC model `Stage`, we have a property `WarehouseSchedule` as `SelectListItem`:

```
public class Stage
{
    public Stage()
    {
        WarehouseSchedule = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WarehouseSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I am doing this:

```
public ActionResult Stage()
{
    var sch = DataRepository.GetSchedules();
    var model = new Stage() {
        WarehouseSchedule = sch
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

`sch` is a list of another class, but while doing above I get the following error:

> Cannot Implicitly convert IList to SelectListitem error.

Comment: `WarehouseSchedule = sch.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Text = x.someProperty, Value = x.ID.ToString() })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, the `SelectList` would be a better way to go, you would have to pass the `sch` list of your schedules object in the constructor of it and and specify the properties that which to be used as display text and which as value for it.

It would be something like:

```
public class Stage
{
    public SelectList WarehouseSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

and then in action you can populate it like:

```
public ActionResult Stage()
{
    var sch = DataRepository.GetSchedules();
    var model = new Stage() 
           {
             WarehouseSchedule = new SelectList(sch,"ScheduleID","ScheduleName");
           };
    return View(model);
}
```

Here above, assuming that the list returned by service layer contains properties named `ScheduleID` and `ScheduleName`.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `Select` method on the `IList` returned by the `GetSchedules` method.

```
public ActionResult Stage()
{
    var model = new Stage() 
    {
        WarehouseSchedule = DataRepository.GetSchedules()
                                         .Select(x=>new SelectListItem {
                                                          Value=x.Id.ToString(), 
                                                          Text=x.Name })
                                         .ToList();
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Assuming your other class has an `Id` property which is numeric type and a `Name` property of string type.